# Standardization before applying ANOVA?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, anova, feature-selection, standardization

I have a matrix where the rows are the data points (samples) and the columns are the features. It is a multiclass (4 classes) problem. On this data I want to apply machine learning classifiers. But first I want to do feature selection by using ANOVA. For this I use Matlab's anova1 method.

Should I standardize (zero mean and unit variance) the feature or samples before applying ANOVA? And if so should I standardize the features (i.e. each column) or the data points (each row)?

Second, should I pick the features which give the highest values after ANOVA or the one which give the lowest (or near zero)?

Comment: Why do you want to do preliminary ANOVA for feature selection? You run the risk of removing features that can affect the relations of other features to class memberships even if they are not themselves related to the classes. There are much better ways to do `feature-selection`; follow the very active tag with that name on this site.

Comment: I'm not sure how ANOVA can help you to find promising features. Have you tried other (more known) feature selection/extraction methods? Take a look on this overwiew-page "Seven Techniques for Data Dimensionality Reduction": http://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/05/7-methods-data-dimensionality-reduction.html **Note:** It's not really technical, but gives you a short summary of how the methods work and which advantges/disadvantages they have. Give it a try!